# Can't compile oracle package because of lock

Tags: oracle, compiler-errors, locking

I want to run `ALTER PACKAGE MONITORING COMPILE;` because the MONITORING package is marked with a red X in SQL Developer, but it takes ages so I stopped it.

I ran the following code to find locks:

```
COLUMN lock_id2 FORMAT A30
select to_char(SESSION_ID,'999') sid ,
   substr(LOCK_TYPE,1,30) Type,
   substr(lock_id1,1,45) Object_Name,
   substr(mode_held,1,4) HELD,
   substr(mode_requested,1,4) REQ,
   lock_id2 lock_addr
FROM dba_lock_internal
WHERE
   mode_requested <> 'None'
   and mode_requested <> mode_held
;
```

I prints `26    Body Definition Pin SCHEMA.MONITORING   None    Excl    00007FFC744CBDE8`.

I then look up the SID 26:

```
SELECT s.sid,
       NVL(s.username, 'ORACLE PROC') username,
       s.osuser,
       p.spid os_pid,
       s.program,
       t.sql_text
FROM   v$session s,
       v$sqltext t,
       v$process p
WHERE  s.sql_hash_value = t.hash_value
AND    s.paddr = p.addr
AND    s.sid = &session_id
AND    t.piece = 0 -- optional to list just the first line
ORDER BY s.sid, t.hash_value, t.piece
/
```

This outputs:

`26 SCHEMA  SYSTEM  3096    ORACLE.EXE (J000)   call SCHEMA.MONITORING.UPDATE_MONITORING_STATUS (  )`.

I then try to run `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '26,3096';`

It tells me `ORA-00030: User session ID does not exist.`. This is probably due to the fact that I already killed the session.

How can I remove the locks for SID 26 that don't want to disappear?

Update:
When I run this:

```
select
   x.*, y.*
from
   v$session x, v$sqltext y
where
   x.sql_address = y.address
and
   y.sql_text like '%MONITORING%';
```

then I get a different serial number: `5479`. Should I use it to stop it? I'm a bit scared now that I mess up stuff by killing random sessions.

The complete output is:

```
00007FFC73BB0A58    26  5479    17225222    00007FFC73F88180    63  SCHEMA  170 2147483644  00007FFC70F229E0        ACTIVE  DEDICATED   63  SCHEMA  SYSTEM  3096    PC-ORACLE   0   PC-ORACLE   ORACLE.EXE (J000)   USER    00007FFC53C7B3E0    2898280916  1sr6azaqc0hfn   0   13.06.18    16803054    00007FFC74434680    1115215392  c6awqs517jpj0   0   13.06.18    16805538                    DBMS_SCHEDULER  2478762354  Update_Monitoring_Status    1070683900      1668888 -1  0   0   0   59  13.06.18    2565    NO  NONE    NONE    NO  OTHER_GROUPS    DISABLED    DISABLED    DISABLED    0       VALID   1   32  VALID   1   32  9   284 library cache pin   handle address  140722259672552 00007FFC744CBDE8    pin address 140721866230184 00007FFC5CD949A8    100*mode+namespace  210629491294211 0000BF9100020003    3875070507  4   Concurrency 0   765 WAITING 764790485   135209515   0   SYS$USERS   DISABLED    FALSE   FALSE   FIRST EXEC  100 00007FFC73F88180    80      00007FFC53C7B3E0    2898280916  1sr6azaqc0hfn   170 0   call SCHEMA.MONITORING.UPDATE_MONITORING_STATUS (  )
```

I get `ORA-00030: User session ID does not exist.` when I use these last parameters to disconnect a session.

Comment: If it's running it's not invalid.

Comment: There is a red X and the error from the application: `2018-06-13 10:18:33 DEBUG JobDAO:400 - Error for KPI - 1000780 : : ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object 
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SCHEMA.MONITORING"
`

Comment: see in your 2nd sql -- the process is J000 -- that is a background job process.  You could try setting the init parameter job_queue_processes=0, that will turn off the background jobs -- then you could try to recompile it

Comment: I finally ended up restarting the database using the net stop/start scripts.